# How to display non printable characters (ASCII codes 0 - 32) in WPF

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, non-printing-characters

I want to display and edit serial data (e.g. NULL, STX, ETX, ENQ, etc. characters) in the text box in WPF. It should be displayed same like Notepad++ as shown here.

[image: Control Characters]

I have tried using textbox, `RichTextBox` in WPF, but only printable characters are shown. Non printable characters (e.g. NULL, STX, ETX, ENQ, etc. characters) are not shown.
Will you please guide me how can I display this?

Comment: First of all, you should not be using a TextBox when you only want to display but not edit a string. Use a TextBlock instead. The way how those characters are shown is up to you. Just replace them in the source string by something you'd like to see, e.g. `var result = source.Replace("\n", "<LF>")`.

Comment: @Victory: What is the source document format that you try to display/edit? And if you are going to edit the data what format you want to use to save it?

Comment: @Jackdaw It will be a text file containing combination of printable and non printable characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display special (non printable) characters in WPF control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266795/display-special-non-printable-characters-in-wpf-control)